# "Time since" a UNIX timestamp

Tags: jquery

Take a UNIX timestamp, example : 1372108039, for a time that has already passed (this was from yesterday).

What I want is to change that into something that says "1 day ago" or "15 hours ago".

I found this code below from a Twitter plugin which takes the time now, the timestamp, finds the difference and outputs accordingly. I have an idea that it can be done simply in JQuery using the code below as a base for that, but have no idea where to start.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function(dateString) {
    var rightNow = new Date();
    var then = 1372108039;
    var diff = rightNow - then;

    var second = 1000,
    minute = second * 60,
    hour = minute * 60,
    day = hour * 24,
    week = day * 7;

    if (isNaN(diff) || diff < 0) {
        return ""; // return blank string if unknown
    }

    if (diff < second * 2) {
        // within 2 seconds
        return "right now";
    }

    if (diff < minute) {
        return Math.floor(diff / second) + " seconds ago";
    }

    if (diff < minute * 2) {
        return "about 1 minute ago";
    }

    if (diff < hour) {
        return Math.floor(diff / minute) + " minutes ago";
    }

    if (diff < hour * 2) {
        return "about 1 hour ago";
    }

    if (diff < day) {
        return  Math.floor(diff / hour) + " hours ago";
    }

    if (diff > day && diff < day * 2) {
        return "yesterday";
    }

    if (diff < day * 365) {
        return Math.floor(diff / day) + " days ago";
    }

    else {
        return "over a year ago";
    }
}, // timeAgo()
```

Comment: There is nice plugin for this case [here](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Ok, that would work :) Would be fun to still see if it could be achieved using that php code. Seems like in principle it should be quite easy.

Comment: You don't need jQuery to do this - there aren't any jQuery features that can compare numbers or do math functions any better than JavaScript already does.

Comment: @Andy what about php now?  You said jQuery, that's JavaScript.

Comment: This code already looks fine. jQuery is primarily a DOM manipulation library, not a mathematics or date library There isn't really anything in jQuery that would help here. If you are getting confused, and actually want to do it in PHP, I'd advise you don't – that would mean your HTML could never be cached without the text being out of sync.

Comment: Yea, I know the code that I posted is php. What I meant was the technique used here in calculating the difference between then and now and using that to give a relative time "X since". I was expecting it to be quite simple to do using the all_singing_all_dancing JQuery, but I guess not - you guys know better than me :)

Comment: The code you've provided is JavaScript (not PHP). It also looks correct. There's no need to change it. Using jQuery will do nothing to improve it. jQuery is a JavaScript library for manipulating the DOM.

Comment: That's just my ignorance. I'm self-learning :) I dropped the code into this JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/HCEXy/), what do I need to add to get it to work?

Comment: You will need to edit the code to make it practical for your use case.  Since we know nothing about what you're trying to do, it would be impossible for us to help.  Right now the code always compares the current time with `1372108039` which is a timestamp that is hardcoded into the JavaScript.  The code would be more practical if you could pass a timestamp to the function as an argument.  I'll leave that up to you as a learning exercise.  Hint: _Maybe the value of_ `then` _should be provided as an argument..._ Good luck!

Comment: Haha. Thanks. Hopefully this question doesn't get closed and I'll be able to post a working link. Eventually.

Comment: There's no need to post a follow up answer or solution for this question.  I'd suggest deleting it. This question is very specific to you and will not help others.  People will have no problem googling to find solutions to related problems... and they don't need to follow your footsteps as you learn JavaScript.